# create new table call Admin with that existing table data

Tags: mysql

I want to create  new  table call Admin with that existing table data.

```
Employee table
+--------+---------+----------+-----+
| emp_Id.  | surname. |  fist_name | staff |  
+--------+---------+-----------+----+
|   100.     |     JOE.     |   ADEX.   | admin 
|    102.    |   JHON.    |   LEO.     | admin
|     103.   |    OLA.     | BABS.   |  admin. |
+--------+---------+--------+-------+


CREATE TABLE `admin` (`username` TEXT,`password` TEXT);
INSERT  INTO  `admin`(`username`, `password`)
VALUES  FROM `employee` `emp_id` =`admin. username` AND `surname` = `admin.password` ;
```

Comment: The manual is pretty good for this sort of stuff - although using a lastname as a password it's not recommended

Answer (score 0):

you could use a create based on select

```
Create table `admin` 
select   `emp_id`,  `surname` 
from `employee`
```